# survey times discrete or continuous?

Tags: discrete-data

If I'm surveying on the times 28 students spend every day on Instagram, and the times are whole numbers such as 10, 40 mins etc, is the data discrete or continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Time is a continuous variable.
The fact that your answers are integer numbers is related to the accuracy of your data. Theoretically you could have something like $10.37$ min.